# Inequality on Hankel function

Tags: inequality

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\rho_{1}>\rho_{2}>0$ and $s=s_1+is_2$ with $s_1>0,\;s_2\in\mathbb{R}$, prove
the estimate
\begin{equation}
 \left|\frac{1+r_n^{(1)}(is\rho_1)}{1+r_n^{(1)}(is\rho_2)}\right| \le C\frac{\rho_1}{\rho_2},
\end{equation}
where $C$ is a positive constant, and $r_n^{(1)}(z)=zh_n^{(1)^{\prime}}(z)/h_n^{(1)}(z)$, $h_n^{(1)}(z)$
is the spherical Hankel function of the first kind.